# Is the trace map continuous on the trace class?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
Let $A$ be trace-class, i.e., $\tr{|A|}<\infty$ where $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$. Then is $A\mapsto \tr{A}$ continuous wrt the uniform topology, SOT or maybe WOT?
I know that $|| A || \le \tr{|A|}$, but I'm curious about other topologies.

Comment: You'll need a bit better precision: the trace map's "norm" depends on the norm (for example) of the space it's defined on. The space of trace-class maps $A$ is exactly the subspace on which "trace" is continuous, _with_ the trace norm on those maps. The right-hand side of your conjectural inequality probably cannot use the uniform-operator-norm of $A$, because trace is not continuous with that norm... So... what more-refined question might you aim to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite-dimensions all of these topologies (trace norm, operator norm, SOT, WOT) coincide on the trace class (which itself coincides with the space of all linear operators on the corresponding Hilbert space) so in this case the trace, unsurprisingly, is continuous.

> As soon as one gets to infinite-dimensions the map $\operatorname{tr}:(\mathcal B^1(\mathcal H),\tau)\to\mathbb F$ is not continuous for $\tau=$ norm, SOT, WOT.

To see this we will construct a sequence of trace-class operators which converge to 0 in the operator norm but the corresponding traces do not converge. Moreover if $\operatorname{tr}$ is not continuous in operator norm it cannot be continuous with respect to *any* weaker topology on the domain (such as SOT or WOT, cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies)).

Let $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of your underlying (separable, infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and define $T_n:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ via $T_n(e_k):=\frac1ne_k$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$ and $T_n(e_k)=0$ for all $k>n$ as well as its linear extension onto all of $\mathcal H$. One readily verifies that each $T_n$

- is of finite-rank, hence trace-class.
- has operator norm $\frac1n$ (as no "matrix element" is larger than $\frac1n$).
- has trace $\operatorname{tr}(T_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n=1$.

As by the second point $\|T_n\|=\frac1n\overset{n\to\infty}\to0$ but $\operatorname{tr}(T_n)=1\overset{n\to\infty}{\not\to}0=\operatorname{tr}(0)$.

Comment: Would the trace map, with $\tau = \| ... \|_{1}$ (the trace norm) be continuous over infinite dimensional trace class operators?

Comment: @Hldngpk Indeed the trace is trace-norm continuous over any Hilbert space. This is a direct consequence of the fundamental inequality $|\operatorname{tr}(A)|\leq\|A\|_1$ for all trace-class operators $A$, see for example Lemma 16.20 in *"Introduction to Functional Analysis"* by R. Meise and D. Vogt (Oxford, 1997).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.