# Weak continuity of the trace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a complex separable Hilbert space and $C^1(H)$ the space of trace class compact operators on $H$. My question is:

Is the trace function $\mbox{Tr}:C^1(H)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous with respect to the weak topology on $C^1(H)$?. I guess that it is just lower semicontinuous,but I'm not shure.

Comment: Every norm-continuous linear functional on a normed space is weakly continuous.

Comment: While Martin's and Ruy's answer is of course correct, let me add a quick side note: If by "weak topology" you really meant "weak **operator** topology" then the answer is no. Equipping the trace class with any operator topology weaker than the one induced by the trace norm (in infinite dimensions), unsurprisingly, turns the trace into a [discontinuous functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3514713).

Answer (score 0):

The weak topology is given, by definition,  by convergence under the norm-continuous linear functionals. So every norm-continuous linear functional is weakly continuous. By the inequality
$$
|\operatorname{Tr}(A)|\leq \operatorname{Tr}(|A|)=\|A\|_1, 
$$
the trace is continuous, so it is in the dual and it thus weakly continuous.